# Is there a faster way to generate keyframes?

Tags: keyframes

I'm using Blender for animation of STL files, by importing tabulated data for position and orientation. To do the animation, I loop through the data and insert keyframes for each location and rotation, using "object.keyframe_insert()"...

For small amounts of data, that works fine, but if I have ~20,000 points of data, Blender uses to long time, and is not responding.

Is there a better way to do this ?